# SOQL Alias a column

Tags: apex, soql

I am wondering how you would do something simple like this in SOQL.

```
select first_name as name from tableA
```

I can not find any documentation on Aliasing a column which is very common in all forms of SQL, does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: I wish this feature existed. I write SOQL queries in R and having to `rename` fields in every tibble I produce gets old fast.

Comment: Ya they make it pretty painful!

Comment: If you need support aliases in SFDC SOQL please up-vote this idea: - https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lEA2QAM

Answer (score 51):

SOQL has very limited aliasing support. You can alias the table, e.g. `SELECT a.name FROM Account a`, but that's of very little use. In most contexts you cannot alias fields.

The one exception is for queries that use aggregations, like `SELECT COUNT(Id) recordCount FROM Account` allows you to alias the result of the aggregation from it's default `expr0` to `recordCount`.

This probobly doesn't do what you're looking for, and you'll have to use some sort of transform in apex, middleware, or on the API client (depending on what and how you're building) to alias columns in non-aggregate use cases.

Answer (score 14):

You can use object aliasing in any SOQL query

**From the SOQL reference guide.....**

> Alias Notation
>
> You can use alias notation in SELECT queries: SELECT count() FROM
>   Contact c, c.Account a WHERE a.name = 'MyriadPubs'
>
> To establish the alias, first identify the object, in this example a
>   contact, and then specify the alias, in this case “c.” For the rest of
>   the SELECT statement, you can use the alias in place of the object or
>   field name.
>
> The following are SOQL keywords that can’t be used as alias names:
>   AND, ASC, DESC, EXCLUDES, FIRST, FROM, GROUP, HAVING, IN, INCLUDES,
>   LAST, LIKE, LIMIT, NOT, NULL, NULLS, OR, SELECT, WHERE, WITH

See page 2 of the reference guide [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/salesforce_soql_sosl.pdf)

You can only use field aliasing with aggregate expressions.  For more info on aliasing with aggregates, take a look here

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_alias.htm

Comment: Note that this is an object alias, not a field alias. Salesforce only allows field aliasing in aggregate expressions. i.e. `GROUP BY`

Comment: Indeed.  I didn't make that clear, will edit the answer to reflect.  Thanks

Comment: @ChrisDuncombe what is the point of object aliasing? Is there any practical use case in SOQL

Answer (score 11):

As Chris mentioned, you can only alias aggregated fields. The syntax to use is like this:

```
SELECT Status, COUNT(id) Total
FROM Case
GROUP BY Status
```

Notice, no "AS" keyword like in vanilla SQL

Comment: You can now alias also Status column in your example: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_alias.htm

Comment: I see the salesforce page of @Sankozi, but still get "only aggregate expressions use field aliasing" even when going to api-level 58

Answer (score 4):

Alias notation also works with the `toLabel()` function in both SOQL and SOSL queries.

> The `toLabel` function supports aliasing. In addition, aliasing is required when the query includes the same field multiple times. For example:
>
> `FIND {Joe} RETURNING Lead(company, toLabel(Recordtype.Name) AliasName)`
>
> — [SOSL Reference: toLabel(fields)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_tolabel.htm?search_text=toLabel)

The above excerpt, shows the use of the alias notation with `toLabel` function in a SOSL query, however, the same syntax works for SOQL queries.

For example, if we have the following Account records in Salesforce:

```
+--------------+--------------------+
| Name         | BillingCountryCode | 
+--------------+--------------------+
| A            | US                 |
| B            | IE                 |
| C            | CA                 |
+--------------+--------------------+
```

Without the `toLabel` alias we would only be able to select one of `BillingCountryCode` or `toLabel(BillingCountryCode)`. If we tried to select both without an alias we would run into an error:

> *duplicate field selected: BillingCountryCode*

Now, if we use alias notiation, we can query for both the Billing Country Code as well as the label as follows:

```sql
SELECT
    Name,
    BillingCountryCode,
    toLabel(BillingCountryCode) BillingCountryLabel
FROM Account
```

Then the above query would produce a query result as follows:

```
+--------------+--------------------+---------------------+
| Name         | BillingCountryCode | BillingCountryLabel | 
+--------------+--------------------+---------------------+
| A            | US                 | United States       |
| B            | IE                 | Ireland             |
| C            | CA                 | Canada              |
+--------------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Interestingly the `toLabel(field) alias` syntax still allows you to return the usual SObject type back instead of `AggregateQuery`. The label data is only accessible via `.get('fieldName')` though of course.

Comment: Only picklist fields, field history, or platform entity fields (or Record Type Name, Description in the SELECT list) support translation.  =(

Comment: I did the same querry but I am not able to access to Opportunity.BillingCountryLabel

Comment: @RaphaelD You need to use [`SObject.get()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) to access the aliased label. e.g  `String label = (String) opp.get('BillingCountryLabel')`

Answer (score 4):

Aliasing like this:

```
select first_name as name from tableA
```

isn't possible in Salesforce SOQL.

Answer (score 3):

**I think the answer is yes you can. Kind of.**

The OP is asking whether you can do this like you can in SQL:

```
select first_name as name from tableA
```

So whilst SOQL doesn't support the above, you can achieve the same effect like this:

```
AggregateResult[] people = [select Firstname Name from tableA group by Id, Firstname];
```

I can see many others have mentioned aggregate queries but nobody has made it clear that you can take advantage of the aliasing possible with the group by query - **the trick is to group by something unique like the Id**.  All the other fields you want to select out must be in the group by clause as well.

Access the result like so:

```
for(AggregateResult person:people) { 
  String theirName = person.get('Name');
}
```

Not sure why this isn't used more widely - it's what I do when I need to alias like you do in regular SQL.

Comment: I think the reason to avoid this, when not needed, is performance, cause this will require extra database effort to group by Id and Name.

Comment: agreed Jeferson!

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing how to reference the field in Apex!

Answer (score 2):

Directly write the alias name 
for example: 
select AccountID account ,count(id) countid from Account

you can also retrieve using get() function by passing the alias name in ' ' quotes 
example: object_reference.get(;

Answer (score 1):

Finally we have found decision how to "rename" column in SOQL without using standart Aggregate function that requires Group by clause in the end, and unfortunately doesn`t allow to export more that 2000 rows in query.

The best way is using `Format(Field) Custom_Name`.
It could be tricky way to use this with some date values or etc. cause function changes format of values in field.

The name of Hero who advice it - Roman Bielei