# Alias with format() function in SOQL

Tags: soql

I need to alias some of our SF fields in a query before I send it out via API. Since alias is not supported in `SOQL` [I have read that a workaround could be to use the `format()`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/340463/55660) function whichs allows to us an alias. But if I write someting like:

```
SELECT format(myField) as Name FROM Table
```

the alias is not being returned. myField might be an `nvarchar` or an `int`.

Anyone who can help me get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes that you are working in Apex (as opposed to some other language).

Field aliasing is not something that SOQL is generally capable of. When we *can* alias a field, the `as` keyword is not used. [The FORMAT() function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_format.htm) only states that it works on date/datetime, number, and currency fields, though it does also appear to work on other field types as well (I've tried a picklist, a text field, an autonumber field, and a formula field returning type Text).

Fields aliased in this way do not appear in the results of a query when you use the "Query Editor" tab in the developer console, but they will show up if you `system.debug()` the results of such a query through anonymous apex.

Accessing the aliased field in apex needs to be done through SObject's `get()` method (unless you're aliasing to an existing field API name on your object, which is not something I'd generally recommend). So given your example `MySObject  rec = [SELECT FORMAT(myField__c) Identifier FROM MySObject];` you could access the aliased field using `rec.get('Identifier');`

When using undocumented features (like the ability of `FORMAT()` to work on other field types), there is a risk that Salesforce could make a change that causes any non-documented usage to no longer work. So I think the generally preferred approach here would be to create a wrapper class to ensure that your data is accessible via the identifiers you want/need.

Example:

```
public class Wrapper {
    String myAlias;
}

MySObject record = [SELECT Id, Field_To_Alias__c FROM MySObject LIMIT 1];

Wrapper wrapped = new Wrapper();
wrapped.myAlias = record.Field_To_Alias__c;
```